# webpack different loader if file size bigger then xxx

Tags: html, angularjs, webpack, task, loader

I use webpack + angularjs 1.x. In directives I need templates file. Now I setup loader for html :

`{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'raw'
}`

But some templates files can be so big, and i dont need all of files every time.

So my question is: Can i setup webpack copy file content to local variable then file size < 1 MB and copy file to output folder in other way